# Add two app icons to the Dock (for Outlook for mac)

Tags: ms-office, dock

I've been using iCal, but one too many sync problems has made me think I should just use the Outlook calendar and it's also my organization's preferred calendar. I want one Outlook icon in the Dock to open to my Inbox and a separate Outlook icon that would open to my Calendar. Is this possible?

I don't want to have to open an Outlook window from inside the app every time I need to restart Outlook. I also frequently close the windows and would like a quick way to open them back up.